# How to apply configuration to nested module through `build.gradle`

Tags: android, gradle

I have a `gradle` project with a nested gradle project. How can I set a configuration on the root `build.gradle` and apply to all nested modules. The structure looks like:

```
 project
   build.gradle
   settings.gradle
   sub-project
       build.gradle
```

inside `settings.gradle`, I includes the `sub-project`:

```
include ":sub-project"
```

in the root `build.gradle`, I have below settings:

```
  android {
   buildTypes {
    staging {
        initWith release
    }
   }
  }
```

It works fine if I manually edit the `build.gradle` in `sub-project`. I wonder how I can pass this setting to the `sub-project` without updating its `build.gradle`

I tried to add below configuration on root `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects { pry -> 
    android {
        buildTypes {
            staging {
                initWith release
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but got this error:

```
Unable to find a matching configuration of project :sub-project:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'staging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
```

Manually add the settings on the nested `build.gradle` works great but `subprojects` way doesn't work. What is the different between these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

inside `project/build.gradle`, use the **allprojects** as below:

```
allprojects { prj ->

    if (!project.hasProperty("android")) {
        return
    }

    // this condition can be used to skip some project
    if (prj.name == "<your-project-name-to-skip>"){
        return
    }

    android {

        ...
        productFlavors {
            staging {
                initWith release
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want the particular settings applied to *sub-projects* only. Replace the **allprojects** with **subprojects**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this configuration overwrite anything? I got compile error after changing that: `compileSdkVersion is not specified.`. It looks like it overwrite some settings on the build.gradle.

Comment: You are working on Android project, right? see my edits

Comment: Yes it is Android project and I have updated my question. I tried your approach but I still get some errors.

Comment: change `debugApiElements` to `stagingApiElements`

Comment: Just FYI, usually, **buildTypes** are `debug`, `release` and your `staging` should be better a kind of product flavor.

Comment: the build configuration is formed as <buildType><ProductionFlavor>, e.g. `debugStagingImplementation`

Comment: if I build a new product flavor, I will get a `debug` and `release` for `staging` flavor, right? This is not what I need.

Comment: Where should I make the change for `stagingApiElements`?

Comment: Inside dependencies {}

Comment: Posting your complete gradle file will be more helpful